# Remove object from array of objects based on value

Tags: arrays, object, filter

I have this array of objects:

```
var data = [{
    "code": "8252",
    "name": "Věšák Sentini, antik mosaz",
  },
  {
    "code": "8253",
    "name": "Věšák Sentini, matný chrom",
  },
  {
    "code": "8254",
    "name": "Věšák Sentini, antik měď",
  },
  {
    "code": "8261",
    "name": "Věšák Kasper I, matný nikl",
  }
]
```

How can I remove the object from array that has **code == 8254** please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get a new array without specified element:

```js
var data = [{
    "code": "8252",
    "name": "Věšák Sentini, antik mosaz",
  },
  {
    "code": "8253",
    "name": "Věšák Sentini, matný chrom",
  },
  {
    "code": "8254",
    "name": "Věšák Sentini, antik měď",
  },
  {
    "code": "8261",
    "name": "Věšák Kasper I, matný nikl",
  }
]

let output = data.filter(x => x.code !== "8254");

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)